# HTML page is not visible in Angular after setting all the routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In signup.component.html I have written this simple code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="signupForm">
        <form>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="fullname" class="form-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter your Name "
                    aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="phone" class="form-label">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number"
                    aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address"
                    -describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password "
                    id="password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my app-routing.module.ts is this :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
// import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './components/contact/contact.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './components/signup/signup.component';
import { StoreComponent } from './components/store/store.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {'path':'store', component:StoreComponent},
  {'path':'login', component:LoginComponent},
  {'path':'signup', component:SignupComponent},
  {'path':'home', component:HomeComponent},
  {'path':'about', component:AboutComponent},
  {'path':'contact-us', component:ContactComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And in header.component.html I am routing to signup page by this :

```
<li class="nav-item" >
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/signup">Signup</a>
</li>
```

But after going to signup page from header link it is giving me blank page, but after removing the  form part and writing anything there, it is giving me result. Same thing is happening to my login page. Writing anything random in p or h tag it is showing, when writing this code it is not.

Please help me out because I just started learning Angular so not able to figure out.

Thanks..

Comment: How is your  'header.component'? Do you have the '<router><outlet>' in app.component.html or somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code 'aria' missed in email inpit field. It is aria-describedby not -describedby. It must be the error.

Comment: Thanks Saradh. I copied the code from bootstrap, may be by mistake I have deleted it. Thank you very much